# Push-Issue: The supplied HTTP URL is not registered in the subscription's parent project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I wanted to add a Push-Endpoint (example.com/push) but receive

```
The supplied HTTP URL is not registered in the subscription's parent project
```

I've already confirmed ownership via Google Webmaster console.

Comment: Can you specify your steps before your get this error?